# Deploying on JBoss EAP 6 using Jenkins and Maven Deploy plugin

Tags: maven, deployment, jboss, jenkins, jboss-eap-6

I am setting up a CI environment to build and deploy java projects to a remote server using mvn jboss-as:deploy goal.

Couple of questions
1. Do i need to do anything specific on jboss standalone.xml to enable hot deployment. For example
auto-deploy:exploded option needs to be enabled?

1. Presently the deployment is manual process: copying the war to deploy folder and then touch the ar file. Do I need to remove the old wars under deploy folder for remote hot deployment to work successfully?
2. Once hot deployment is performed using jenkins, if a server restart is performed, older version of the war is getting deployed. Any clue on this?

Please help.

Comment: Can somebody please respond

Comment: Which plugin are you using?

Comment: jboss as maven plugin

Comment: With the jboss-as-maven-plugin there is no way to deploy exploded WAR's at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue. Since previously the war was deployed manually, I had to remove the war files from Standalone/deployments folder. On a server restart the war under this folder would be deployed causing older version of the application to show up.